# C# console instantly close on other pcs

Tags: c#, console

I'm new in C# and want to get better.
So I wrote some kind of "banking system" and everything I wanted worked and finally I build the project.
On my computer everything works but when one of my friends try to open the .exe file the console window appears for like 1ms and instantly close and I dont know why it works on my computer but not on others.

I hope that someone can help me with this problem and thanks to everyone who tries to help me :)

Comment: He should start it from the command line (cmd.exe) so any error message stays on screen and you are able to read it.

Comment: Try to write `Console.ReadKey();` at the end of the main method

Comment: All console programms will inherently end, unless you do something in main to keep them open. This is a majr difference to any GUI or Game, wich has a loop that will keep it alive - until canceled.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work either.
And on my PC everything works like it should, but with my two friends who tried it, the console closes directly again.

Comment: It looks like they both don't have the .NET core installed and probably that's why, thanks for the quick help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have some input implemented inside your app so it should stay open in the first place.It seems to me that its not even starting on your friends pc.
You probably built your app with higher .net version than your friend's pc has installed.
Check your target .net version in Project properties.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like they both don't have the .NET core installed and probably that's why, thanks for the quick help :)